# How to check next element in the array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm learning and currently trying to write a simple multiple choice quiz. I am not allowed to write it simply with if else statements.
I'm trying to make it so that it asks the question the user inputs the answer (that's all fine) but a separate class works out if it's right or not. 
Where my code has the array with a blank index I'm wondering how after the first iteration it would check the next index when that method was called upon again in the next question. I tried to use a for each but then get an error regarding not every path has an outcome. 
`private static readonly string[] answerArray = new string[5] { "C", "A", "B", "A", "C" };`

```
    public static bool AnswerCalc(string ain)
    {
        if (ain == answerArray[])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Correct");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry that's wrong");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I had it as a bool as that's how I was keeping score.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if an array contains an item simply:

```
var aInArr = arr.Contains("A");
```

This is a LINQ expression built into .net.

One way to implement this as a non-extension method targeting array is like so:

```
public bool Contains(string[] arr, string inputStr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (item == inputStr[i])
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Once it runs out of items in the array it will break out of the for loop curly brackets and return `false`.

Note: for brevity I reduced the result but the .net way to do this is to use an `IEnumerable` on a generic input instead of an array and use `foreach` instead of `for`.

```
public static Contains<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, T compared)
{
    foreach (var item in input)
    {
       if (item == compared)
           return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Another way without LinQ is using the namespace `System.Array`: `string[] rightAnswers = { "Ans1", "Ans2" };   Array.Find(rightAnswers, item => item == "Answer1");   OR   Array.Exists(rightAnswers, item => item == "Answer2");`

Answer (score 0):

If you store an integer in the class containing this method, you can increment it at the end of the function call (make sure you reset it to 0 when it reaches the length of the array). Use this integer between the square braces like so: `if (ain == answerArray[intValue])`

If you need more help then let me know and I'll be happy to update this with more information.